# Build very simple spinner in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, spinner

I got the Jquery plugin from google to detect a "mousehold" event for JQUERY

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
    $('#button').mousehold(function(){

        //Do something to implement a spinner

    });
   });
```

The mousehold is working fine , how do i keep incrementing the value of a text box till mousehold is true, i want to implement a simple incrementing spinner

Comment: you can view the page source of `http://remysharp.com/demo/pip_ticker.html` which has an example.

Comment: Link to mousehold plugin -> http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/

Comment: Maybe you just need a numeric up down? http://www.misfitgeek.com/2011/06/numeric-up-down-input-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make a text box value increment till the mouse is hold on the button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $('#button').mousehold(function(){
        $('#spinnerText').val(++count);
    });
});
```

The text box is as below -

```
<input type="text" id="spinnerText">
```

Comment: Then what do you need. Can you explain ?